# Help optimizing db architecture

Tags: postgresql, explain

I have the following query which takes forever to execute (it never does, if I rewrite it a little it executes, but also takes forever)

```
        SELECT
          DISTINCT
          pac.product_id,
          pac.advertising_channel_id
        FROM
          public.advertising_channels ac
          JOIN public.products_advertising_channels pac ON ac.id = pac.advertising_channel_id
          LEFT JOIN public.iovox_numbers numbers ON numbers.product_id = pac.product_id
          AND numbers.link_type = ac.iovox_link_type
        WHERE
          phone_number IS NULL
          AND (
            pac.status = 'ENABLED'
            OR pac.status = 'INHERITED'
            AND (
              EXISTS(
                SELECT
                  1
                FROM public.master_activity_advertising_channels maac
                WHERE
                  (
                    EXISTS(
                      SELECT
                        1
                      FROM
                        public.sodata_activities a
                      JOIN public.current_offers co ON co.activity_id = a.id
                      JOIN public.sodata_products p ON p.id = co.product_id AND p.offer_type <> 'BOOSTER_SITE' AND p.state = 'running'
                      JOIN public.sodata_customers c ON p.customer_id = c.id AND c.calltracking_status = true
                      WHERE
                        a.master_activity_id = maac.master_activity_id
                        AND p.id = pac.product_id
                    )
                  )
                  AND maac.advertising_channel_id = pac.advertising_channel_id
                  AND maac.enabled = TRUE
              )
            )
          )
```

Which operates on relatively small tables (up to few hundreds thousands records in the biggest one, `products_advertising_channels`.

The explain before I added indexes on `products_advertising_channels.status`:

```
Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=0.29..1899444612.35 rows=88366 width=24)
   Join Filter: (numbers.link_type = ac.iovox_link_type)
   ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..1899410622.78 rows=88366 width=16)
         Join Filter: (pac.advertising_channel_id = ac.id)
         ->  Seq Scan on products_advertising_channels pac  (cost=0.00..1899402337.41 rows=88366 width=12)
               Filter: ((status = 'ENABLED'::editor.product_advertising_channel_status) OR ((status = 'INHERITED'::editor.product_advertising_channel_status) AND (SubPlan 1)))
               SubPlan 1
                 ->  Nested Loop  (cost=5088.00..5088.09 rows=1 width=0)
                       ->  HashAggregate  (cost=5087.72..5087.73 rows=1 width=9)
                             Group Key: (a.master_activity_id)::text
                             ->  Nested Loop  (cost=5083.25..5087.72 rows=1 width=9)
                                   ->  Nested Loop  (cost=5082.84..5085.07 rows=1 width=13)
                                         ->  Unique  (cost=5082.55..5082.56 rows=1 width=202)
                                               ->  Sort  (cost=5082.55..5082.56 rows=1 width=202)
                                                     Sort Key: ((offers.applicable_period = '(,)'::tsrange)) DESC
                                                     ->  Seq Scan on offers  (cost=0.00..5082.54 rows=1 width=202)
                                                           Filter: ((product_id = pac.product_id) AND (applicable_period @> LOCALTIMESTAMP))
                                         ->  Index Scan using sodata_activities_pkey on sodata_activities a  (cost=0.28..2.50 rows=1 width=18)
                                               Index Cond: ((id)::text = (offers.activity_id)::text)
                                   ->  Index Only Scan using sodata_products_pkey on sodata_products p  (cost=0.42..2.64 rows=1 width=4)
                                         Index Cond: (id = pac.product_id)
                       ->  Index Scan using ma_ad_channels_on_ma_id_and_advertising_channel_id on master_activity_advertising_channels maac  (cost=0.28..0.36 rows=1 width=9)
                             Index Cond: ((advertising_channel_id = pac.advertising_channel_id) AND ((master_activity_id)::text = (a.master_activity_id)::text))
                             Filter: enabled
         ->  Materialize  (cost=0.00..1.10 rows=7 width=8)
               ->  Seq Scan on advertising_channels ac  (cost=0.00..1.07 rows=7 width=8)
   ->  Index Scan using no_duplicate_link_type_per_product on iovox_numbers numbers  (cost=0.29..0.35 rows=3 width=24)
         Index Cond: (product_id = pac.product_id)
```

I saw the SeqScan with cost of 1.9billion and thought adding index on status is what's missing, so I did (which is strange since status is enum type and I thought such columns are efficient enough without indexes).
Explain after indexes:

```
Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=1534.36..896013552.66 rows=88366 width=24)
   Join Filter: (numbers.link_type = ac.iovox_link_type)
   ->  Hash Join  (cost=1534.08..895979563.09 rows=88366 width=16)
         Hash Cond: (pac.advertising_channel_id = ac.id)
         ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on products_advertising_channels pac  (cost=1532.92..895979189.53 rows=88366 width=12)
               Recheck Cond: ((status = 'ENABLED'::editor.product_advertising_channel_status) OR (status = 'INHERITED'::editor.product_advertising_channel_status))
               Filter: ((status = 'ENABLED'::editor.product_advertising_channel_status) OR ((status = 'INHERITED'::editor.product_advertising_channel_status) AND (SubPlan 1)))
               ->  BitmapOr  (cost=1532.92..1532.92 rows=176092 width=0)
                     ->  Bitmap Index Scan on products_advertising_channels_idx_on_status  (cost=0.00..11.64 rows=1203 width=0)
                           Index Cond: (status = 'ENABLED'::editor.product_advertising_channel_status)
                     ->  Bitmap Index Scan on products_advertising_channels_idx_on_status  (cost=0.00..1477.09 rows=174889 width=0)
                           Index Cond: (status = 'INHERITED'::editor.product_advertising_channel_status)
               SubPlan 1
                 ->  Nested Loop  (cost=5088.00..5088.09 rows=1 width=0)
                       ->  HashAggregate  (cost=5087.72..5087.73 rows=1 width=9)
                             Group Key: (a.master_activity_id)::text
                             ->  Nested Loop  (cost=5083.25..5087.72 rows=1 width=9)
                                   ->  Nested Loop  (cost=5082.84..5085.07 rows=1 width=13)
                                         ->  Unique  (cost=5082.55..5082.56 rows=1 width=202)
                                               ->  Sort  (cost=5082.55..5082.56 rows=1 width=202)
                                                     Sort Key: ((offers.applicable_period = '(,)'::tsrange)) DESC
                                                     ->  Seq Scan on offers  (cost=0.00..5082.54 rows=1 width=202)
                                                           Filter: ((product_id = pac.product_id) AND (applicable_period @> LOCALTIMESTAMP))
                                         ->  Index Scan using sodata_activities_pkey on sodata_activities a  (cost=0.28..2.50 rows=1 width=18)
                                               Index Cond: ((id)::text = (offers.activity_id)::text)
                                   ->  Index Only Scan using sodata_products_pkey on sodata_products p  (cost=0.42..2.64 rows=1 width=4)
                                         Index Cond: (id = pac.product_id)
                       ->  Index Scan using ma_ad_channels_on_ma_id_and_advertising_channel_id on master_activity_advertising_channels maac  (cost=0.28..0.36 rows=1 width=9)
                             Index Cond: ((advertising_channel_id = pac.advertising_channel_id) AND ((master_activity_id)::text = (a.master_activity_id)::text))
                             Filter: enabled
         ->  Hash  (cost=1.07..1.07 rows=7 width=8)
               ->  Seq Scan on advertising_channels ac  (cost=0.00..1.07 rows=7 width=8)
   ->  Index Scan using no_duplicate_link_type_per_product on iovox_numbers numbers  (cost=0.29..0.35 rows=3 width=24)
         Index Cond: (product_id = pac.product_id)
```

It now still shows the scan but with cost of 900k. I want to use this query to create a materialized view which I'd refresh every day. Please advise what's missing in the DB/tables setup. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It is difficult to be certain what the problem is without `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` output, but I guess that speeding up the oft-repeated sequential scan in the subquery will have a positive effect:

```
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS btree_gist;
CREATE INDEX ON offers USING gist (product_id, applicable_period);
```

Comment: thanks you for your answer and recommendation! We already had btree_gist and I added the composite index from your answer and eventually rewritten my query which somehow now runs instantly

Comment: Than it's probably best to close the question, right?

Comment: The additional context that (coincidentally?) you also provided in your answer and discussion to [this question about subplans](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67497704/20042973) a couple of years ago helped me better understand how the pieces fit together here, including how you knew that the subplan was an '_oft-repeated sequential scan_'

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe yes, I think closing is the best option to ensure clarity on the status - could you please do it? I don't have enough reputation on this exchange to do it :)

Comment: I can only cast a close vote. But I would be surprised if you couldn't close your own question. On the other hand, if @user20042973 would like to keep the question, why not.